# How to convert the date in Ionic date picker to 'Y-m-d H:i:s' In Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I have datetime picker in my Ionic 4 app and I am sending that date and time but the date and time format should be `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

This is my **html**:

```
<ion-datetime formControlName="startchallenge" displayFormat="DD-MM-YY HH:mm:ss" pickerFormat="DD-MM-YY HH:mm:ss" placeholder="Select Date" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate"></ion-datetime>
```

I am getting this date and time in my **ts** file and then I have to convert this date and time and send in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

This is my **ts**:

```
datetime: any;
this.datetime = this.acceptchallengeform.value.startchallenge
```

I want to send this date and time as this format: `Y-m-d H:i:s`. Now it is sending as `2019-03-15T06:11:52Z`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think date formate you want for backend is not valid it should be like `'Y-M-D H:m:s' please confirm it.

Comment: Yes, not possible with `<ion-datetime>`. You can change the value of the input with displayFormat and pickerFormat, but the output will always be a valid ISO 8601 datetime string.

Comment: Have you tried picker-format="Y-m-d H:i:s", like this?

Comment: @Mohan. Yes but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your **ts** file:

```
let workOutDate=this.acceptchallengeform.value.startchallenge;
workOutDate=workOutDate.replace('T',' ');
workOutDate=workOutDate.replace('Z','');
```

And then send the final date because you are getting this date format from the date-picker `2019-03-15T06:11:52Z` and after changes this will go `2019-03-15 06:11:52`.

So this solved my problem because I was sending this date to the payment service and It was accepting this date `2019-03-15 06:11:52`.